# Numeration in listoftables for longtable with multiple pages

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, page-numbering

i have longtables which span about 2-4 pages, with captions at the end of the tables. Therefore in the listoftables the numeration is the last page for each longtable, but I'd like it to be the first one.

I was not able to find a solution to this problem.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here a minimal example. The table has two pages, is placed on page 2 and 3, and the listoftabels shows numbering 3, which i want it to be 2:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{longtable, ltxtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-ltxtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline 
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ 
\caption{Title}
\label{tbl_trends_overview}
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{\jobname-ltxtable.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please can you add a minimal example?

Comment: Sure, sorry i didn't do it right away. Now i added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. new command `\mtcaption{Title}`  after begin and `\caption[]{Title}` at the end.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{longtable, ltxtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\newcommand{\mtcaption}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-ltxtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\noalign{\mtcaption{Title}\label{tbl}}
\hline 
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\
A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ A&B \\ 
\caption[]{Title}
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{\jobname-ltxtable.tex}
\end{document}
```